# View can't reuse for multiple textfiled's left View

Tags: ios, swift

I'm facing the problem when I create a 1 padding view for 3 different `UITextField` Left view.

Add into 3 different `UITextField` as left view.

for  1 `TextFeild` its output fine but for all `TextFeild` getting blank scree.

code is here.

[image: for 1 Textfeild]

```
let paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 40))

txtlink.leftView = paddingView
txtlink.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
txtlink1.leftView = paddingView
txtlink1.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

txtlink2.leftView = paddingView
txtlink2.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

I don't know what is problem. something view related problem i guess.

Comment: i think you should create 3 different left views, or if you want in lots of text fields then you should create a category class or custom TextField class.